# How can the cursur location be set to a specific cell in tkinter grid?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a program for editing csv files, it works nicely other than that whenever you open a file, the cursor goes to the upper left hand corner (i.e. `[0][0]`).  I want it to be in the *bottom* left hand corner (I have my reasons).  I've looked around a bit, but I couldn't find anything to set the cursor position.

Here is a screenshot of the associated window with some random data:

[image: Screenshot of the associated window]

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Note: The original code isn't mine, I'm just modifying it, so I don't know what everything does.

Comment: Your can use `<widget>.focus()` to try to focus that widget.

Comment: @TheLizzard How do I know what the widget is?  Should it have a name somewhere?  I tried this, just as a test to put it somewhere else: `self.currentCells[1][1].focus()`, but it didn't work.  `self.currentCells[1][1]` contains something that looks like `.!application.!text44` is that the widget?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us a minimal working example. Right now I have no idea how your code works. Also if `.focus()` doesn't work, try `.focus_force()`

Comment: I'm not sure what I would need to show as a "minimal working example" as I don't know exactly how it works, as I said in my edit, the original can be found here: https://github.com/ssebs/csveditor and mine should be visible here: https://replit.com/@RowanAckerman/csvEditor-1#mod/_base_funcs.py

Comment: Look at line [126](https://github.com/ssebs/csveditor/blob/94aeb08295772650d2bea11aaee6e4238554ad5e/csv_editor.py#L126). It reads: `self.defaultCells[0][0].focus_force()`. Basically it forces the focus on the top left widget. Instead change it to: `self.defaultCells[0][-1].focus_force()`. That should focus the bottom left widget. If it focuses the top right widget, change the `0` and the `-1`.

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm not sure what all of this means, I've found that tkinter's errors aren't wonderful, but here's the output:

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/runner/csvEditor/mod/_htky_funcs.py", line 67, in newLineH
    self.loadCells(same=True, plus=True, skip=True)
  File "/home/runner/csvEditor/mod/_base_funcs.py", line 136, in loadCells
    self.defaultCells[0][-1].focus_force()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 737, in focus_force
    self.tk.call('focus', '-force', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!application.!text4"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235946/discussion-between-rowan-ackerman-and-thelizzard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a two-dimensional list of entries, it's just a matter of setting the focus to the first widget in the last row with `focus_set`:

```
last_entry = self.entries[-1][0]
last_entry.focus_set()
```

If you don't have a two-dimensional list of entries, then use whatever data structure you have to get the first entry on the last row, and then call `focus_set()` on it.

Here's a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import csv
from io import StringIO

class CsvViewer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

    def load(self, csv_reader):
        self.entries = []
        for row_num, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
            entry_row = []
            self.entries.append(entry_row)
            for column_num, column in enumerate(row):
                entry = tk.Entry(self, width=20)
                entry.insert("end", column)
                entry_row.append(entry)
                entry.grid(row=row_num, column=column_num, sticky="nsew")
        # set focus to the last widget
        last_entry = self.entries[-1][0]
        last_entry.focus_set()

root = tk.Tk()
viewer = CsvViewer(root)
viewer.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

data = """
First, Last, user
Bob, Johnson, bjohn
Mark, Phillips, mphil
""".strip()

f = StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
viewer.load(reader)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OP wants the cursor to be in the *bottom left* corner.

Comment: @TheLizzard: thanks. For some reason I read bottom-right.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also can you please explain the difference between `.focus`, `.focus_set` and `.focus_force`?

Comment: @TheLizzard: that's all covered in the available documentation (eg: `help(tk.Entry.focus)` etc). The canonical description is in the [tcl/tk focus man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/focus.htm)

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks!  Your example works beautifully, but the it doesn't set the focus in mine.  I think that has something to do with your use of `Entry` and mine of `Text`.  I'm trying to adapt it to using `Entry`, but it isn't easy.  If there is some way to do this for `Text` please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: @RowanAckerman: this example works equally well with the text widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for all of you're assistance.  I still can't figure out how to get this to work.  Here's the link to my code: https://replit.com/@RowanAckerman/csvEditor-1#mod/_base_funcs.py, the relevant area is around line 143.  If you have some time, I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look.  Please fork it before modifying anything!  Thanks so much!

Comment: I got it!!  There was something that focus_force-ed every cell, I got rid of it and it works perfectly now!